# Pycharm debugger - set maximum list length

Tags: python, pycharm

Im trying to debug a python script with Pycharm and i get array of 100 elements ( exactly ) during an API call to AWS cloudformation, Im pretty sure that Pycharm is filtering out the rest of the elements.

I find this for Intellij ( but its not available on Pycharm: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/09/debugger-working-with-sub-ranges-for-arrays-and-lists/ )

Any idea ( maybe a license issue ? )

Thanks .

Comment: Do you mean to say that you only see 100 elements max in the debugger window for your list item even if the received list is of size > 100?

Comment: find the problem. this is a pagination feature of Boto3 library ( python library for aws cloudformation )

Answer (score 0):

find the problem. this is a pagination feature of Boto3 library ( python library for aws cloudformation )

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the list actually is longer than 100 items? In my experience, PyCharm is pretty explicit when it doesn't show the full list of items:

[image]

If it is indeed PyCharm that is hiding items You could manually evaluate an expression such as `my_list[100:]` to see items starting from the hundredth item, or in my case from the three hundredth item:
[image: PyCharm variable explorer showing a long list]

Comment: Ah... I see now that you had found the root problem. I'll leave this answer here hoping that it might help someone else with a similar question.